# Menubar dropdown grabbing text from background

Tags: jquery, html, css

Recently I added responsive drop-down for menu-bar in order to support touch devices but I ran into an interesting issue and cannot figure out the root cause. Basically the drop-down seems to be transparent and its influenced by the text from the background feed post in content section. It seems that that drop-down reads the background text title because if I hover over that text the drop-down closes as if it thinks i am trying to bring focus to the title.

[Click to see the image and it will all make sense.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuiev.png)

```css
#nav {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #4085C6;
 padding: 6px;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-top-color: #4085C6;
 border-right-color: #4085C6;
 border-bottom-color: #4085C6;
 border-left-color: #4085C6;
 margin: 0px;
 width: 960px;
}
#nav > a {
    display: none;
} 
#nav li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav li a
{
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
}
#nav li a:active
{
 background-color: #c00 !important;
}
#nav span:after
{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 0.313em solid transparent; /* 5 */
 border-bottom: none;
 border-top-color: #4086C4;
 content: '';
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 right: -0.313em; /* 5 */
}
/* first level */
#nav > ul {
 height: 3.75em;
 background-color: #4086C4;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#nav > ul > li {
 width: 157px;
 float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
 border-right-width: 8px;
 border-right-color: #3779b3;
 border-right-style: solid;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > a,
#nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a {
 background-color: #3779b3;
 color: #FFF;
 list-style-type: none;
}
/* second level */
#nav li ul {
 background-color: #3779b3;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 width: 20em;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul {
 left: -1px;
}
#nav li ul a {
 font-size: 1.25em;
 border-top: 1px solid #4086C4;
 padding: 0.75em;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover,
#nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
 background-color: #4086C4;
 list-style-type: none;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */
{
 #nav {
 width: 100%;
 position: static;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px #4785C6;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 outline-color: #4086C4;
 outline-style: solid;
 background-color: #4086C4;
 color: #4086C4;
 padding: 0px;
 border-top-color: #4086C4;
 border-right-color: #4086C4;
 border-bottom-color: #4086C4;
 border-left-color: #4086C4;
 }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */
{
 html {
  font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
 }
    #nav {
        position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
    }
 #nav > a {
  width: 3.125em; 
  height: 3.125em; 
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-color: #4086C4;
  position: relative;
 }
 #nav > a:before,
 #nav > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  top: 35%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  content: '';
 }
 #nav > a:after {
  top: 60%;
 }
    #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
    #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
  display: block;
    }
 /* first level */
    #nav > ul {
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    #nav:target > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
 #nav > ul > li > a {
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0.833em;
 }
 #nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3779b3;
 }
 /* second level */
    #nav li ul {
        position: static;
  padding: 1.25em;
  padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
        <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
            <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
            <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Adult</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="adult/indoor_soccer.html">Indoor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="adult/indoor_league.html">Indoor League</a></li>
                        <li><a href="adult/outdoor_soccer.html">Outdoor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="adult/wsl_schedules.html">WSL Schedule</a></li>
                        <li><a href="adult/srbijada2014.html">Srbijada 2014</a></li>
<li><a href="adult/contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Youth</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="youth/code_of_ethics.html">Code of Ethics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="youth/team_tryouts.html">Team Tryouts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="youth/team_camp.html">Team Camp</a></li>
                        <li><a href="youth/team_registration.html">Team Registration and Payments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="youth/mikro_soccer.html">MiKro Soccer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="youth/tournaments.html">Tournaments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="youth/contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="board_members.html">Board</a></li>
                <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use z-index property in the CSS.

```
#nav li ul {
    background-color: #3779b3;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 20em;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```